# An intermediate functional space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

is there an intermediate functional space $Y$ such that the Sobolev space $W^{1,N}$ compactly embeds in $Y$ and $Y$ continuously embeds in $L^N$, where $N$ is the ambient space dimension?
Thank you

Comment: I am not quite sure to understand the question. Are you talking about the Sobolev/Lebesgue spaces *on the whole $R^N$* or simply on some bounded domain?

Comment: Oh sorry, on some bounded domain.

Comment: The question is too vague. Why can't you just take $Y=L^{N}(\Omega)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

well, if you are interested in open bounded domains, then it is trivial: $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ is compactly embedded in any Sobolev space of real order $W^{s,2}(\Omega)$, which is continuously (in fact, even compactly) embedded in $L^2(\Omega)$, whenever $s\in (0,1)$ (for $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^2$, but not only).

if you need a reference, see e.g. thm. 1.4.3.2 in grisvard's *elliptic problems in nonsmooth domains*, where only lipschitz boundary of $\Omega$ is assumed.